# Streets of Rage 2 (Switch) Extended Options Screen

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-switch-lite, streets-of-rage-2

I have Streets of Rage 2 for my Nintendo Switch Lite. It came on the Sega Genesis Classics compilation. There's a secret code to access an Extended Options screen:

> On the main menu, hold A+B on the second controller while selecting "Options" with the first.

The problem is it requires a second controller to hold A+B. Is there another way to do this trick on the Nintendo Switch with just one controller?

Comment: That could be easily doable with a couple of joycons, but you have the Lite one...